# Can't compile a OneOrMany enum which allows to push values into it

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create an enum that can hold zero, one or many values (somehow classical) and with which I would interact by a single `push(new_value:T)` method. It could have either `None` value (empty), `One` value or `Many` value (basically a vector/slice).

I'm trying to create a wrapper for a flexible type that can be either a single value or a vector.

Here is what I have written but that I can't compile

```
enum NoneOneOrMany<T> {
    None,
    One(T),
    Many(Vec<T>),
}

struct FormValues<T> {
    value: NoneOneOrMany<T>,
}

impl<T> FormValues<T> {
    pub fn new() -> FormValues<T> {
        FormValues { value: NoneOneOrMany::None }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, new_value: T) {
        match self.value {
            NoneOneOrMany::None => self.value = NoneOneOrMany::One(new_value),
            NoneOneOrMany::One(existing_value) => {
                let mut vec = Vec::<T>::new();
                vec.push(existing_value);
                vec.push(new_value);
                self.value = NoneOneOrMany::Many(vec);
            }
            NoneOneOrMany::Many(ref mut vec) => {
                vec.push(new_value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:17:15
   |
17 |         match self.value {
   |               ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
18 |             NoneOneOrMany::None => self.value = NoneOneOrMany::One(new_value),
19 |             NoneOneOrMany::One(existing_value) => {
   |                                -------------- hint: to prevent move, use `ref existing_value` or `ref mut existing_value`
```

My overall intent was to then be able to do something like this:

```
fn print_form_value<T: Debug>(x: FormValues<T>) {
    match x.value {
        NoneOneOrMany::None => println!("Empty"),
        NoneOneOrMany::One(val) => println!("Holds one value => {:?}", val),
        NoneOneOrMany::Many(vec) => println!("Holds several values => {:?}", vec),
    }
}

fn test_oneOrMany() {
    let mut x = FormValues::<u32>::new();
    x.push(1);
    x.push(2);

    let mut y = FormValues::<u32>::new();
    y.push(3);

    let mut z = FormValues::<u32>::new();

    print_form_value(x);
    print_form_value(y);
    print_form_value(z);
}
```

It's probably a silly classical borrowing question but I just started to use Rust. Is there a way I can `move` `existing_value` from it's current owning `Option` into a vector without having to clone it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move-out the old value by temporarily [`replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html)-ing the `value` with a `None`, and then fill it back later:

```
pub fn push(&mut self, new_value: T) {
    let old_value = replace(&mut self.value, NoneOneOrMany::None);
    self.value = match old_value {
        NoneOneOrMany::None => {
            NoneOneOrMany::One(new_value)
        }
        NoneOneOrMany::One(existing_value) => {
            NoneOneOrMany::Many(vec![existing_value, new_value])
        }
        NoneOneOrMany::Many(mut vec) => {
            vec.push(new_value);
            NoneOneOrMany::Many(vec)
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to `.clone()`, though this will incur an extra move of T from `self.value` to `old_value`

Consider using the [`smallvec`](https://docs.rs/smallvec/0.3.3/smallvec/struct.SmallVec.html) crate instead. The `FormValues<T>` type is equivalent to `SmallVec<[T; 1]>`. It is also written with carefully crafted [unsafe](https://docs.rs/smallvec/0.3.3/src/smallvec/lib.rs.html#298) [code](https://docs.rs/smallvec/0.3.3/src/smallvec/lib.rs.html#340) so that the unnecessary move is not needed.

Comment: thanks a lot @kennytm it indeed solved it! Out of curiosity why do you say that `SmallVec<[T;1]>` would prevent the move (I am guessing you are referring to `let old_value = replace(&mut self.value, NoneOneOrMany::None);`) ?

Comment: @Boris When `self.value` was `One(t)`, there would be two moves of the `t`: first from `self.value` to `old_value`, second from `old_value` to the vector. With `SmallVec`, there would be only one move directly from the stack `[T; 1]` to the heap vec. Of course for `T == u32` this is really not a big deal, it is only a problem if `T == SomeHugeStruct`.